# How to pull data from an array using SQL

Tags: sql, hiveql, hue

If I have a string column with the following data:

```sql
+-------+----------------------------+
| Row # |        Array Column        |
+-------+----------------------------+
|     1 | {apple;coconut;mango}      |
|     2 | {coconut;pear;grapes}      |
|     3 | {strawberry;mango;coconut} |
|     4 | {}                         |
|     5 | {january}                  |
+-------+----------------------------+
```

How can I pull out only the rows that have mango or nothing in it?

Result:

```sql
+-------+----------------------------+
| Row # |        Array Column        |
+-------+----------------------------+
|     1 | {apple;coconut;mango}      |
|     3 | {strawberry;mango;coconut} |
|     4 | {}                         |
+-------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: "You fell victim to one of the classic blunders, the most famous of which is 'Never get involved in a land war in Asia,' but only slightly less well known is this: 'Never put array data in a column!' "

Answer (score 1):

If the column is a string and not an actual array.

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE ArrayColumn='{}' 
OR ArrayColumn like '%mango%'
```

If the column is indeed an array

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE size(ArrayColumn)=0
OR array_contains(ArrayColumn,'mango')
```